# mysql table number increasing over time

Tags: php, mysql

I want to increase one of the rows of mysql table over time:
this is my table:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `materials` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `meat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `iron` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stone` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `straw` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `wolfskin` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `wolffang` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `coin` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `diamond` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `steel` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='test';


INSERT INTO `materials` (`userid`, `meat`, `lumber`, `iron`, `stone`, `straw`, `wolfskin`, `wolffang`, `coin`, `diamond`, `steel`) VALUES
(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I want to increase meat row +20 each minutes.
How can I do this with php and mysql?
my means is how can increase the table row number in mysql and show it online in php.
I dont want to insert or update it with php. I want it keep increasing even if no one isnt online with php
Thank you

Comment: do you want to insert into table each min.explain clearly

Comment: update query executed by cron

Comment: I thought a simple `UPDATE` will do, and execute it by cronjob / scheduler

Comment: If you want to insert new row then you can do that by cronjob

Comment: But I dont want to insert or update it by php.

Comment: I want it increase over time even if no one is online with php

Comment: Then do as others have suggested. Write some PHP code to do the update and execute it by Linux Cron job or Windows Scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all.

I have write a code like this for my need:

```
CREATE EVENT `e_update` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON `COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO 
UPDATE materials SET meat = meat+1;`
```